# Microsoft Visual Web Developer cannot connect to SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-web-developer-2010

When I try to connect to database from Microsoft Visual Web Developer, I keep getting the same error message.

"This server version is not supported. You must have Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or later."

I'm currently using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, so technically I shouldn't be facing this problem at all. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Did you also check the Compatibility Level of the database you are trying to connect to?

Comment: Beginner question here: How to check compatibility?

Comment: Right-Click on your database (in SSMS) choose "Properties" and navigate to "Options" in the Properties Window. There you can see (and select) the Compatibility Level of this individual database.

Comment: it says SQL Server 2000 (80). Does this means that its the cause? If yes, then is there any other methods to connect to database, such as via SqlConnectionStringBuilder?

Comment: Yes, this is very likely the cause. No, I'd guess there's no other way because it will require functionality that is only supported by the higher Compat Level. Did you try selecting a higher Compat Level? I admit I never had to do this before myself.

Comment: See [MSDN: ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) Compatibility Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level)

Comment: I cannot select a higher level because the compatibility level is locked to 2000 only.

Comment: Best, you check over at [dba.se] - could be that you just do not have the necessary privileges to change this.